# start from hours and minutes with time_bucket_gapfill

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

I have the next forecast table:

```
   |        id       |      timestamp      |     name    | temp      |
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
    |        1       | 2022-01-16 12:40:06 |  Bancal 1   |     22    |
    |        2       | 2022-01-16 12:58:05 |  Bancal 1   |     21    |
    |        3       | 2022-01-16 13:22:00 |  Bancal 1   |     30    |
    |        4       | 2022-01-16 13:30:20 |  Bancal 1   |     10    |
    |        5       | 2022-01-16 13:59:06 |  Bancal 1   |     15    |
    |        6       | 2022-01-16 15:40:00 |  Bancal 2   |     15    |
    |        7       | 2022-01-16 15:54:06 |  Bancal 1   |     18    |
    |        8       | 2022-01-17 10:30:05 |  Bancal 2   |     23    |
    |        9       | 2022-01-17 11:20:00 |  Bancal 1   |     12    |
    |        10      | 2022-01-17 11:32:07 |  Bancal 3   |     28    |
    |        11       | 2022-01-17 13:30:06 |  Bancal 1   |     23    |
```

I want to make a query by intervals of 1 hour and fill in the empty spaces, but I want it to start exactly at the indicated hour and minute, if I say to start from the date time `'2022-01-16 12:38:52'` then the intervals of 1 hour should be:

```
2022-01-16 12:38:52
2022-01-16 13:38:52
2022-01-16 14:38:52
2022-01-16 15:38:52
       .
       .
       .
2022-01-17 09:38:52
2022-01-17 10:38:52
2022-01-17 11:38:52
2022-01-17 12:38:52
2022-01-17 13:38:52
```

Use the time_bucket_gapfill function of timescaledb but the gaps are made at the beginning of the hour:

```
    SELECT time_bucket_gapfill(interval '1 hour', timestamp,) AS init,
       name,
       avg(temp) AS avg_temp
    FROM forecast
    WHERE timestamp >= '2022-01-16 12:38:52' AND timestamp<= '2022-01-17 13:38:52'
    GROUP BY name, init
    ORDER BY init;

|          init            |    name  |  avg_temp 
2022-01-16 12:00:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |
2022-01-16 12:00:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  21.5
2022-01-16 12:00:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
2022-01-16 13:00:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  18.3333333333333333
2022-01-16 13:00:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
2022-01-16 13:00:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |  
2022-01-16 14:00:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
2022-01-16 14:00:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  
2022-01-16 14:00:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |  
2022-01-16 15:00:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |  15
2022-01-16 15:00:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  18
2022-01-16 15:00:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
...
2022-01-17 09:00:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  
2022-01-17 10:00:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |  23
2022-01-17 10:00:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
2022-01-17 10:00:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  
2022-01-17 11:00:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |  
2022-01-17 11:00:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  12
2022-01-17 11:00:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  28
2022-01-17 12:00:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |  
2022-01-17 12:00:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  
2022-01-17 12:00:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
2022-01-17 13:00:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
2022-01-17 13:00:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  23
2022-01-17 13:00:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |
```

The result of avg is unexpected as it takes the data from `'2022-01-16 12:00:00' to '2022-01-16 13:00:00'` instead of `'2022-01-16 12:38: 52' to '2022-01-16 13:38:52'`
Is there a way for time_bucket_gapfill to do those gaps?

EXPECTED:

```
|          init            |    name  |  avg_temp 
2022-01-16 12:38:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |
2022-01-16 12:38:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  20.75
2022-01-16 12:38:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
2022-01-16 13:38:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  15
2022-01-16 13:38:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
2022-01-16 13:38:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |  
2022-01-16 14:38:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
2022-01-16 14:38:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  
2022-01-16 14:38:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |  
2022-01-16 15:38:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |  15
2022-01-16 15:38:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  18
2022-01-16 15:38:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
...
2022-01-17 09:38:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |  23
2022-01-17 10:38:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |  
2022-01-17 10:38:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  28
2022-01-17 10:38:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  12
2022-01-17 11:38:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |  
2022-01-17 11:38:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  
2022-01-17 11:38:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
2022-01-17 12:38:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |  
2022-01-17 12:38:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  23
2022-01-17 12:38:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
2022-01-17 13:38:00.000000 | Bancal 3 |  
2022-01-17 13:38:00.000000 | Bancal 1 |  
2022-01-17 13:38:00.000000 | Bancal 2 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [generate_series](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-srf.html) function.

> generate_series(start, stop, step interval)

The third parameter you can write your expect interval. In your case that might be `1 hours`

```
SELECT *
FROM generate_series('2022-01-16 12:38:52'::timestamp,'2022-01-17 13:38:52'::timestamp,'1 hours') v
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=3cdb715d437a15841cf838b202bc3550)

**EDIT**

You can try to use CTE or subquery to make a calendar to represent time gap per `name`, then use `LEAD` window function to get the timestamp interval for `JOIN` condition.

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT  
         name,
         generate_series('2022-01-16 12:38:52'::timestamp,'2022-01-17 13:38:52'::timestamp,'1 hours') dt
  FROM forecast
)
SELECT  t1.name init,
        t1.dt,
        avg(coalesce(t2.temp,0)) AS avg_temp
FROM (
   SELECT *,LEAD(dt) OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY dt) n_dt
   FROM CTE 
) t1
LEFT JOIN forecast t2
ON t1.name = t2.name  AND t2.timestamp BETWEEN t1.dt AND t1.n_dt
GROUP BY t1.name,
        t1.dt
ORDER BY t1.dt
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=1bc7797ad9162da473d52d36180c1665)

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding, I have problems with the result of the complete query, I edited the question to be more clear

Comment: @Isra I see.I edited my answer you can try it